# Problema con pruebas unitarias: Junit y el framework Mockito

Tags: java, junit-5, mockito, testing

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer test unitarios y dobles con Junit y el framework Mockito, pero no consigo el resultado esperado en un test en concreto con 'mocks'. Hago un `assertThat` que debería de devolver test positivo, en cambio, me devuelve un error que dice `Mockito cannot mock this class`.
Se trata de una clase llamada 'Console' que debe de imprimir y recoger valores desde el teclado del usuario, pero claro, en las pruebas unitarias esto se debería de 'mockear' para evitar en antipatrón 'prueba interventora', donde el test pida datos al desarrollador, es decir, necesito 'mockear' una entrada de usuario.
Esta clase 'Console' es como una pequeña fachada de la típica clase BufferedReader de java.

Os paso las clase implicadas:

La clase Console:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Console {

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public String readString(String title) {
        String input = null;
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            this.write(title);
            try {
                input = this.bufferedReader.readLine();
                ok = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.writeError("characte string");
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return input;
    }

    public int readInt(String title) {
        int input = 0;
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            try {
                input = Integer.parseInt(this.readString(title));
                ok = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                this.writeError("integer");
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return input;
    }

    public char readChar(String title) {
        char charValue = ' ';
        boolean ok = false;
        do {
            String input = this.readString(title);
            if (input.length() != 1) {
                this.writeError("character");
            } else {
                charValue = input.charAt(0);
                ok = true;
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return charValue;
    }

    public void writeln() {
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void write(String string) {
        System.out.print(string);
    }

    public void writeln(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

    public void write(char character) {
        System.out.print(character);
    }

    public void writeln(int integer) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

    private void writeError(String format) {
        System.out.println("FORMAT ERROR! " + "Enter a " + format + " formatted value.");
    }
}
```

..y la clase ConsoleTest:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

public class ConsoleTest {

    @Mock
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    @InjectMocks
    private Console console;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before(){
        initMocks(this);
        this.console = new Console();
    }
    @Test
    public void givenConsoleWhenReadStringThenValue() throws IOException {
        String string = "yes";
        when(this.bufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(string);
        assertThat(this.console.readString("title"), is(string));
    }
}
```

También os paso el archivo pom.xml (me huelo que por allí hay errores)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>

    </modules>

    <artifactId>solution.java.swing.socket.sql</artifactId>
    <groupId>usantatecla.tictactoe</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Gracias y saludos a la comunidad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anotaste la instancia de `Console` con `@InjectMocks` pero no estás aplicando el patrón de inyección de dependencias, ya que la instancia `BufferedReader` que necesita `Console` la estas creando dentro de `Console`, por lo tanto *Mockito* no puede inyectar la instancia de `BufferedReader` que definiste como un mock en `ConsoleTest`.

Para resolver el problemas debes aplicar la inyección de dependencias de forma correcta modificando la clase `Console` para que reciba la instancia de `BufferedReader` mediante un constructor.

```java
public class Console {

    private final BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    public Console(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
       this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
    }

    ....
}
```

Como estas usando @`InjectMocks` *Mockito* va a inicializar `console` antes de ejecutar cada `@Test`, inyectando el mock de BufferedReader, por lo tanto puedes eliminar esta línea `this.console = new Console();`.

NOTAS

No necesitas usar `this` cada vez que quieras usar un atributo de clase, es una redundancia, solo es necesario cuando existe una variable local dentro del mismo scope que el atributo de clase, Por ejemplo:

```java
...
    private final BufferedReader bufferedReader; // atributo de clase

    public Console(BufferedReader bufferedReader) { // variable local dentro del mismo scope
       this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
    }
...
```

Existen otras formas de aplicar la inyección de dependencias, La inyección basada en constructor es la más recomendada (*Constructor Based Injection*).

Referencias

[Mockito @InjectMocks – Mocks Dependency Injection](https://www.journaldev.com/21887/mockito-injectmocks-mocks-dependency-injection)